Convergent series for fixed x
Prove that the series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)$ is convergent for fixed x in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and determine the sum. Prove, that the sum does not depend on x in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$
My original proof was as follows:
Considering that $\cos^2$ does not depend on n, and can hence be considered as a constant. Which means I can rewrite the series as:
$$ \cos^2(x)  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)$$
The series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)$ can be written as
$$  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x) = sin^{2\cdot0}(x)+sin^{2\cdot 1}(x)+...sin^{2n}(x) $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x) = 1+ \sin^{2}(x)(1+\sin^{2}(x)+ \sin^{4}(x)...$$
Which I further rewrite:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x) = 1+ \sin^{2}(x)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x))$$
Which can be simplified too
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)- \sin^{2}(x) (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin^{2n}(x)) = 1$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)(1- \sin^{2}(x)) = 1$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)= \frac{1}{1-\sin^{2}(x)}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)= \frac{1}{\cos^{2}(x)}$$
Which means that I can rewrite the original equation
$$ \cos^2(x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)= \frac{1}{\cos^{2}(x)} \Rightarrow 
\cos^2(x)\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(x)}= 1 $$
Which means that $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)$  is convergent for fixed
x in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and the sum is equal to 1. I have also proven that the sum does not depend on x in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and only the value of n
My teacher told my solution was entirely incorrect and that I would completely start over. However, I have no clue how else to solve the task. I was told to exploit trigonometric identities, which I then did in proof, but I am simply out of ideas now.
EDIT: NEW PROOF
Given the series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)$, for $x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ both $\cos^2(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ are bounded between 0 and 1. So, $\cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)$≤ $\sin^{2n}(x)$ which is a geometric series with a common ratio r = $\sin^{2}(x)$
Since 0<$\sin^{2}(x)<1$ for x $\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, the geometric series  $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)$ converges absolutely.
I find the sum using the formula of infinite geometric series, $S=\frac{a}{1-r}$, where a=$\cos^2(x)$ and r= $sin^2(x)$
$$S= \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)} =\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = 1 $$
Thus the sum is also independent of x $\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

It looks good to me!

Are you sure? So my teacher made a mistake then? Should I ask him to regrade my assignment, essentially?

@MarcusK.Johnson? Can you please confirm?

Your teacher is right. You didn't prove the convergence of $(\cos^2x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}x$, because you assumed that of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}x$. However, you did prove that if it converges then  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)=1$.

@AnneBauval Can you provide a hint to how I can prove it? Do I need to start completely over?

No Thomas, you don't. Simply notice that if $|x|<\pi/2$ then $\sin^2x<1$, and  $|r|<1\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ converges (to $\frac1{1-r}$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

I see, that makes sense. But how can I then prove that the sum does not depend on x?

@ThomasLarsson use the fact that $∑n=0∞sin2n(x)=1cos2(x)$

@Mathslover Perhaps you might re-express your comment with MathJax.

@AnneBauval I have updated my answer with my new proof, using your suggestions. Thoughts? Is it still incorrect?

It is ok. Just replace $0<$ with $0\le$ in "$0<\sin^2(x)<1$".

In order to help you understand your mistake, suppose that you were asked to analyze the convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\cdot 3^{2n}$. If your reasoning were correct, we would get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\cdot 3^{2n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}=1+9+81+729+\cdots=1+9(1+9+81+\cdots )=1+9\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}$$
Then, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}-9\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}=1$,
that is,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}=-\frac{1}{8}.$$
Finally,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\cdot 3^{2n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}=2\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)=-\frac{1}{4},$$
which makes no sense since the given series has only positive terms. This explicitly shows that we must be careful when manipulating infinite sums. The problem here is that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{2n}$ is not convergent.
In general, the fact that you find a number at the end after a manipulation does not prove convergence.  The usual properties that were used are valid only if the convergence of the series is given, known or proven. In your case, you were asked to prove it. After proving convergence, the manipulations above become valid and could be used to obtain the sum of the series.
The way to prove convergence has already been given in the comments:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sin^{2}(x))^n$$
converges because it is a geometric series with ratio $r=\sin^{2}(x)\in(-1,1)$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)$ is also convergent and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(x)\sin^{2n}(x)=\cos^2(x)  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin^{2n}(x).$$
Finally, you can calculate the sum using your reasoning or using the formula for the sum of the geometric series.

I have updated my answer with my new proof, using your suggestions. Thoughts? Is it still incorrect?
